# injecting Value in Spring always null

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I am  following this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-el-hello-world-example/) but and when trying to run the application it runs with this error stack

```
    Jul 18, 2014 3:45:23 AM org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext@1f2f0ce9: display name [org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext@1f2f0ce9]; startup date [Fri Jul 18 03:45:23 EEST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
Jul 18, 2014 3:45:23 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from file [C:\Users\Yasha\workspace3\Test\spring-beans.xml]
Jul 18, 2014 3:45:23 AM org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext obtainFreshBeanFactory
INFO: Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext@1f2f0ce9]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1ba22e94
Jul 18, 2014 3:45:23 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1ba22e94: defining beans [itemBean,customerBean]; root of factory hierarchy
Jul 18, 2014 3:45:24 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory destroySingletons
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1ba22e94: defining beans [itemBean,customerBean]; root of factory hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerBean' defined in file [C:\Users\Yasha\workspace3\Test\spring-beans.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean '#{itemBean}' while setting bean property 'item'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named '#{itemBean}' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:84)
    at SpringEl.app.main(app.java:8)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named '#{itemBean}' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:387)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:971)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:246)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269)
    ... 18 more
```

What I am doing wrong here ?

I have simply followed the first step of this tutorial which is injecting value via XML

spring-beans.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="itemBean" class="SpringEl.Item">
        <property name="name" value="itemA" />
        <property name="qty" value="10" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="customerBean" class="SpringEl.Customer">
        <property name="item" value="#{itemBean}" />
        <property name="itemName" value="#{itemBean.name}" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Customer.java:

package SpringEl;

```
public class Customer {

    private Item item;

    private String itemName;

    public Item getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(Item item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }

    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customer [item=" + item + ", itemName=" + itemName + "]";
    }

}
```

Item.java:

package SpringEl;

```
public class Item {

    private String name;

    private int qty;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getQty() {
        return qty;
    }

    public void setQty(int qty) {
        this.qty = qty;
    }
}
```

and eventually my main class

app.java

```
   public class app {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("spring-beans.xml");


        Customer obj = (Customer) context.getBean("customerBean");
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the `spring-context` dependency is specified properly in the `pom.xml` file.  Here is an example:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.stack.overflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>example</name>
    <description>example</description>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

The `spring-context` dependency has its own dependency on the `spring-expression` artifact, which is basically Spring EL.

My hunch is that Spring EL is not being placed on the classpath.  So when the Spring IOC container begins to read the `spring-beans.xml` configuration file, it does not resolve the expression `#{itemBean}` and it treats the expression as a String literal.  This causes an issues because the `item` property on the `customerBean` bean expects a type of `SpringEl.Item` as opposed to a `String`.

Fixing the dependency in the `pom.xml` file will place Spring EL on the classpath and allow the proper resolution of the expression to take place, ultimately satisfying the dependency with a bean of the proper type.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer after I do that the itemName is not Resolved and instead of getting "ItemA"I am getting "#{itemBean.name}"

Comment: yes regarding spring-beans.xml It is correct in my code it must have been a mistake while copying

Comment: @user3135757 Is Spring-Context in your pom file?

Comment: yep     
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
     <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

Comment: maybe some stuff were deprecated in the new version ?

Comment: I wouldn't think Spring EL would be deprecated.  I'm going to work through that example quick and see if I can replicate.  Are you using spring-core 4.0.6?

Comment: @user3135757 Well its not the configuration or the classes.  I'm wondering if its the main method.  I was able to get my demo up and running by copying all of your code/config.

Comment: @user3135757 Could you post the full stack trace?

Comment: did it work with you ? maybe it is something with the pom.xml ?

Comment: @user3135757 Here are the files I used: https://gist.github.com/kmb385/e5555bdc43f209c96889

Comment: @user3135757 I wonder what the difference was.  I'm guessing Spring EL wasn't being loaded, which caused the expression not to resolve in the configuration file, so the Spring IOC container read the value for the property as a String literal.  I'll adjust the answer with this information.

Comment: http://www.diffnow.com/?report=p072k checkout the difference. I can't understand as well is it because I have added some unnecessary dependencies ?

Comment: ah by the way , the dependencies were added using maven ui in eclipse.

Comment: @user3135757 I bet it was the dependency on that earlier version of Spring, it specified `<dependency><groupId>org.springframework</groupId><artifactId>spring</artifactId><version>2.5.6.SEC03</version></dependency><dependency>`  You don't want that old version sitting out on the classpath.  The same goes for that old version of `spring-web`.

Comment: @user3135757 Glad I could be of help!  Nice question!